# Use Converted string to class type for casting

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have this following code which is it has to many if. I know that converting string name to class type is that class type can be use only on runtime.

```
ViewType vtype;
Series sser = new Series();

       if (Convert.ToString(vtype) == "Bar")
        {
          ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.BarDrawOptions)sser.View).ColorEach = true;
        }
        else if (Convert.ToString(vtype) == "StackedBar")
        {
          ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.StackedBarSeriesView)sser.View).ColorEach = true;
        }
        else...

sser.DataSource = dtTable;
```

To shorten my code i've come up to this idea

```
Series sser = new Series();
string classtype = DevExpress.XtraCharts.Native.SeriesViewFactory.GetType(vtype).ToString();
//classtype returns a value 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.BarDrawOptions', 'DevExpress.XtraCharts.StackedBarSeriesView' etc
Type type = Type.GetType(classtype);
((type)sser.View).ColorEach = true;             
sser.DataSource = dtTable;
```

I want ColorEach to be cast base on the `string classtype` like if the `string classtype` returns a value of `DevExpress.XtraCharts.BarDrawOptions` i want to convert the string to  its class type and cast it to `sser.View`

Is this possible to achieve or other way?

Comment: You want all the `ColorEach` to be `true`? I ask this because if so we have a short way to do.

Comment: nope. just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Use this Dictionary to pair the view types and their corresponding ColorEach to set accordingly
Dictionary<Type,bool> colorEaches = new Dictionary<Type,bool>();
colorEaches[typeof(DevExpress.XtraCharts.BarDrawOptions)] = true;
colorEaches[typeof(DevExpress.XtraCharts.StackedBarSeriesView)] = true;
//.....
bool value;
Type viewType = sser.View.GetType();
if(colorEaches.TryGetValue(viewType,out value)){
   //Suppose your `ColorEach` should be present in all the types added to the Dictionary
   viewType.GetProperty("ColorEach").SetValue(sser.View, value);
}else {
  //your own code
}
```

Comment: should i add everything on colorEaches like `colorEaches[typeof(DevExpress.XtraCharts.SideBySideBarSeriesView)] = true;`

Comment: @Snippet yes, the use of `Dictionary` here is to replace your `if statements`, but as I said, you should be sure all the types added to that dictionary should have `ColorEach` property, otherwise you have to check for the `GetProperty(..)` result (it should be != null). If you just need to set all the `ColorEach = true`, we don't need `Dictionary`, we just need the code `viewType.GetProperty(...)...`. That's a technique called `Reflection`.